# Will disabling replication on Cloud SQL Postgres cause Downtime on Master

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

I am using Cloud SQL Postgres and a read replica is attached. The Cloud SQL instance is regionally highly available
If I disable the replication and then re-enable it, will it cause any downtime to the master database?
If I bring it up and re-enable replication (after two hours for example) will it also degrade performance, while the replica catches-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling or re-enabling replication restarts the replica (not the master instance) as advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/manage-replicas#disabling_replication).

In order to disable replication you can run the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [REPLICA_NAME] --no-enable-database-replication
```

Disabling High Availability in your Master does cause your master to restart as advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ha#disabling_on_an_instance)